# Origin http://localhost:1716 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery, json, wcf, iis

I have this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:81/Test/Service.svc/SetJSON`. Origin `http://localhost:1716` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

when I calls wcf web service using jquery.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: webmethod,
    data: '{"data":"Darshana"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("Unavailable");
    }
});
```

why is that?

any help. thanx..

Comment: This is because the port is different I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember how I got this error and when. But, as lots of people having this problem I thought to post what I did.

WCF - IService

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "SetJSON?data={data}")]
string SetJSON(string data);
```

WCF - Service

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = 
    AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service : IService
{
    public string SetJSON(string data)
    {
        return data;
    }
}
```

WCF - web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"
             crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
....

<services>
  <service name="RnDService.Service">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"
        binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"
        contract="RnDService.IService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Jquery call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:81/Test/Service.svc/SetJSON?data=" + "{ \"dl\":" + datalist + " }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.toString());
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        debugger;
        alert("Error Occured!");
    }
});
```

not 100% sure what solved my problem. Anyway this will help someone. :)

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, because you're accessing a different port it's not on the same [origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

You'll need to enable Cross Origin Resource Sharing on the service that runs on port 1716.

Without knowing what you're trying to do, a configuration like [this](http://enable-cors.org/#how-iis7):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Should allow you to test, although for production it's advisable to whitelist appropriate domains rather than using a wildcard.

Comment: You'll need to customise it based on your configuration.

Comment: worked for  me. Added this in web.config for an ASP.net MVC4.5 project

Answer (score 2):

Different port, trying setting `dataType: 'jsonp'`

Comment: then comes with this GET http://localhost:81/Test/Service.svc/SetJSON?callback=jQuery1710770164709771052_1332392664912&{%22data%22:%22Darshana%22}&_=1332392682691 400 (Bad Request) error

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by Apache mod_proxy module. Enable modules:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Then add:

```
ProxyPass /your-get-url/ http://localhost:1716/
```

Finally, pass proxy-url to your script.

Answer (score 0):

If you use localhost:port in Angular.js, then make sure you escape your port number like this:

```
var Project = $resource(
       'http://localhost\\:5648/api/...',
          {'a':'b'}, 
          {
            update: { method: 'PUT' }
          }
      );
```

See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1243 for more info on it.

Answer (score -1):

I've written a [blog post (Accessing JSON data from a “local” data source is not permitted)](http://senchabits.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/problem-accessing-json-data-from-a-local-data-source-is-not-permitted/) that is essentially zenio's solution, but with step-by-step directions. You set up a reverse proxy in Apache so that it forwards a local URL to the port that hosts the JSON data (basically, forwarding it to the "remote" data source).

Comment: The blog post is apparently marked private, so I can't see it. Not useful.