# IIS Expess 8 not sending Access-Control-Allow-Origin with VS2013 Dev

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

I am using VS2013 with IIS8. My application accesses a server on a different IP to login. I had success doing the access from another Windows box running Webstorm. Now my app is running in VS2013 and I am getting this error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/Token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '`http://localhost:2757`' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

I have tried adding the following to my web config and also to the IIS Express Config file:

web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

applicationhost.config

```
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <clear />
            <add name="X-Powered-By" value="ASP.NET" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        </customHeaders>
        <redirectHeaders>
            <clear />
        </redirectHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Still I am getting the same message.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this. Also how can I tell if the Access-Control-Allow_Headers has been set by looking at Fiddler?

Comment: Your port is different so...Refer to this post that addresses a similar problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816591/origin-http-localhost1716-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Answer (score 0):

I have a running web api project which can accept all types of headers, requests, cors is also enabled, etc and can be called from anywhere. Though i haven't deployed my project on IIS server but so far its running successfully for me on localhost.

Try this. May be it'll solve your problem.

I am assuming that the project you have created on VS 2013 is a web api project.

Follow these steps:-

1)  Open nuget package manager console in your web api project.

2)  type Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors and install it

3)  Once successful type Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi and install it.

4)  check your web.config file for following entries if they are there then remove/comment 
    them.

add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"

add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*"

add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"

5) Now come to your controller file and import the namespace.  using System.Web.Http.Cors;

6) Now at the controller level type [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] to allow all types of origins, headers and methods to be accepted by the controller.

So far this is working out for me.